# Why i am getting error on hosting my website on Heroku by Github repository?

Tags: web, heroku, web-deployment, web-development-server

I am trying to hosting my website through Heroku by using my Github Repository, i am getting an error in code. What should i do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvf7K.png)

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
 !     No default language could be detected for this app.
            HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
            See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Are you building a flask-based python app? Another language? How are you doing it? Provide more details so you can be assisted.

Comment: Hi Devanshu, Hope this would help you https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask